# Plugin 'modeler' not found. Autorest generating TypeScript proxy

Tags: typescript, autorest

I am trying to generate TypeScript proxy for the PetStore.yaml sample via AutoRest but I am not able to do it. I get an error:

> Plugin '**modeler**' not found.

The proxy generation runs fine for c#, java, Go, nodejs, python, but for TypeScript and Ruby just fails with this error.

I have AutoRest v.2.0.4302 running on node v.8.11.4 on Windows 10.

Does someone know a solution to this problem?